# When does Fermat's little theorem not hold for coprimes $a$ and $p$ , but $p$ being non-prime and why?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

When does Fermat's little theorem not hold for coprimes $a$ and $p$, but $p$ being  non-prime and why?
I tested some non-prime values of $p$ and it seems to still hold.

Comment: Do you want to find composite $n$ that do not satisfy $$(a,n)=1\,\Rightarrow\, a^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod{\! n}$$

If so, $n$ is the one you want iff it is composite and not [Carmichael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're interested in the case where $a$ is not divisible by $p$; this assumption allows us to write Fermat's little theorem in the form $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. Let's try $a=3$ and $p=4$: $$3^{4-1}=27 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}.$$ Clearly we've run into a problem, since $3 \neq 1$. So we've shown that $a$ and $p$ being coprime is not a sufficient condition for this theorem to hold.

One may, however, *generalize* Fermat's little theorem to every case where $a$ and $n$ are coprime using [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). Thus, $$a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}.$$ Since $\varphi(n)=n-1$ when $n$ is prime, our initial statement of Fermat's little theorem directly follows from this more general formula.

Let's use this to check our first case. Since $\varphi(4)=2$, we have $3^2 = 9 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, exactly as we expect!

As for seeing why $a$ and $p$ being coprime is not a sufficient condition for Fermat's little theorem to hold, it really depends on your preferred proof! You can see a list of proofs on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_little_theorem); all of them use the assumption that $p$ is prime at one point or another. Try dropping this assumption and see if you can figure out why doing so "breaks" the proof.